# pythonic way of parsing a string into a dictionary with dict comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

For a given string

```
key = "test: abc :bcd,ef:1923:g, x : y : z\nkey2 :1st:second\n  etc :values:2,3,4:..."
```

I would like to parse the string to store into a dict with the first token as key and the rest elements as a value list, something like the following result:

```
{'test': ['abc', 'bcd,ef', '1923', 'g, x', 'y', 'z'], 'key2': ['1st', 'second'], 'etc': ['values', '2,3,4', '...']}
```

I have

```
def parseLine(line):
    return list(map(str.strip, line.split(":")))

result = {parseLine(line)[0]:parseLine(line)[1:] for line in str_txt.split('\n')}
print(result)
```

But in the expression of the dict comprehensions, the function parseLine is invoked twice to set key and value for the dict as `parseLine(line)[0]:parseLine(line)[1:]`.

Is there a better way to re-write the dict comprehensions?

Comment: Do you insist on `result` being a one-liner? Writing a for loop and then just assign `parsed_line = parse_line(line)` once to later access it severel times doesn't seem unpythonic to me.

Comment: @JulianFock The number of lines does not matter and yes, the for loop always works. The question is just an attempt, maybe it is a good case that I should not use comprehensions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{lst[0]:lst[1:] for lst in map(lambda s: list(map(str.strip, s.split(":"))), key.split('\n'))}
```

It gives:

```
{'test': ['abc', 'bcd,ef', '1923', 'g, x', 'y', 'z'],
 'key2': ['1st', 'second'],
 'etc': ['values', '2,3,4', '...']}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` inside the comprehension to apply the function, and then destructure the results.

```py
result = {k: v for k, *v in map(parseLine, str_txt.split('\n'))}
```

Note also that if you're using `parseLine` only for this, you can rewrite it without the conversion to `list`:

```py
def parseLine(line):
    return map(str.strip, line.split(":"))
```

Comment: No need for `list(v)`; assigning to `k, *v` already makes `v` a `list`, so you're copying it unnecessarily; `k: v` would get the same effect faster.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yes, just realised that. I was under the impression the argument unpacking operator created a tuple, but upon testing it turns out to be a list.

Comment: Yeah, it's an understandable mistake; when you receive `*args` for a function, it's a `tuple`, but they decided to go with `list` instead of `tuple` in PEP3132 because it made it easier to do "further processing of the result".

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

s = "test: abc :bcd,ef:1923:g, x : y : z\nkey2 :1st:second\n  etc :values:2,3,4:..."

s = re.sub(r'[^a-z0-9,]',' ',s)

print ({ x.split()[0]:x.split()[1:] for x in s.split("\n") })
```

Output:

```
{'test': ['abc', 'bcd,ef', '1923', 'g,', 'x', 'y', 'z'], 'key2': ['1st', 'second'], 'etc': ['values', '2,3,4']}
```